# Getting an error "pytest: command not found" while running a Python test from CircleCI

Tags: python, selenium, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am trying to learn CircleCI but must say, finding it very difficult to use. I am trying to run my Selenium project code written in Python language but getting pytest: command not found error. I have mentioned the PyTest installation in my requirement.txt file, I also tried to install the PyTest by running the below command but still getting the same error.

```
- run: pip install pytest --user
```

Here is my config.yml file

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@2.0.3


jobs:
  example-job:

    
    docker:
    - image: circleci/python:3.6.1

    
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: pip install pytest --user
      - python/install-packages:
          args: pytest --user
          pkg-manager: pip
          pypi-cache: false
      - run: 
          command:
            pytest businessObjects/test_Login.py


workflows:
    example-workflow:
      jobs:
        - example-job
```

Error is

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
pytest businessObjects/test_Login.py
/bin/bash: pytest: command not found

Exited with code exit status 127
CircleCI received exit code 127
```

It must be some basic mistake but tried a lot and am now stuck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Checkout this [https://discuss.circleci.com/t/bin-bash-line-1-pytest-command-not-found/38648] and  this [https://discuss.circleci.com/t/bin-bash-line-1-pytest-command-not-found/38648]

Comment: Maybe remove `--user` from this line `- run: pip install pytest --user`

Comment: Thanks, @Akzy for the comments - I am getting a page not found error while clicking on that link.

Comment: Thanks, @Jortega - When I remove the --user line then I am getting "Permission error"

Comment: What is the output for `python --version` right before this line `- run: pip install pytest --user`?

Comment: Hey @Jortega - I am getting the version as Python 3.6.1

Comment: Try `- run: python -m pip install pytest`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245770/discussion-between-jortega-and-naseem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to run my code in CircleCI. Posting my config.yml here in case someone else needs help. Thanks, @jortega for trying to help, appreciate your effort.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  python: circleci/python@2.0.3
jobs:
  build_and_test: # this can be any name you choose
    executor: python/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - python/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: pip
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: python -m pytest
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/project
          paths: businessObjects
        - .

workflows:
  test_my_app:
    jobs:
      - build_and_test
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to deal with these kind of issue with circleci is to use the option "ReRun job with SSH"

This would allow you to login to the circleci build instance and try out the installation commands

```
pip install pytest --user
```

or

```
python -m pip install pytest
```

or any command which would fix the issue

The command with which you do not get the error pytest is invalid command , can be used in circleci config

Comment: Thanks for the response. Like @jortega also suggested, I used python -m pip install pytest and getting Permission denied: error

Same issue when we run with ReRun job with SSH